# jquery remove nonbreakingspaces

Tags: jquery, html

Well, i have a table that is generated dynamically and i don't have access to the source code. Each `<tr>` has a single `<td>` and inside a `<td>` i have:

```
<td><label>sdsd</label><input text /><label>uuyti</label><select></select></td>
```

it happens that i am using css, and i want the fields on the two rows to be perfectly aligned, but on the second row, i have a nbsp between the second label and the select, so i want to remove that nbsp but i don't know how to reach it with jquery.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove all `&nbsp;` you can use the following:

```
$("tr td").html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, "");
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/MQJ4P/).

If you want to place a `&nbsp;` after the second label you can use `eq()` and `after()`

```
$("tr td label:eq(1)").after("&nbsp;");
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/MQJ4P/2/).

Comment: thanks, this works, but unfortunately the html that is coming from the server (Dynamic Web(stay away from that crap)) is very uneven, so i had to add the extra space where there wasn't one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("tr td").each(function(index, html){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()+"&nbsp;");
     });
```

this appears to be working on jsfiddle.  still testing

Comment: @André give me a second.  just caught it's between the label and select

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. my td lost all of it's controls and was filled with all the text that was inside, control or not. and it had the spaces...

Comment: @André I've been trying that as well. I  put in one more edit, that was a typo on my part to prevent losing the controls.

Comment: this being maybe to hard, can we try the other way around? i want to add a nbsp after my select in the other row...

Comment: @André  above works on jsfiddle to 'add' an '&nbsp;' after the select.  i'm upping Mark's answer to your original question